# How to produce jar with sbt assembly without scala dependency

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I have simple sbt project with one java class without scala dependency:

```
package com.example;

class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

And `build.sbt`:

```
name := """test-sbt"""

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

mainClass in assembly := Some("com.example.Hello")
```

Also `assembly.sbt` in `project/`

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")
```

Command `sbt assembly` produce one fat jar with scala library inside. How to produce fat jar without scala dependency inside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found solution in sbt-assembly documentation:

I need add this to  `build.sbt`:

```
assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false)
```